How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+1/1!+1/2!+...+1/n!$
How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+1/1!+1/2!+...+1/n!$ rigorously?
I have read many threads regarding the natural constant e, but couldn't find out how to prove this.

We use the binomial expansion
$$
(1+x/n)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k.
$$
Now because for $k > n$, the binomial coefficient is $0$, we can extend the sum to infinity
$$\begin{align}
(1+x/n)^n
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k} \frac{x^k}{k!} \\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},
\end{align}$$
because its a ratio of two polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$.

Technically, you need the dominated convergence theorem to get the last step - it isn't true in general if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k}=b_k$ that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$$

Rule of thumb : everything works with the exponential, but you're absolutely right.
